# how can I solve the problem where I get the error horizontal dimensions mismatch in octave

Tags: math, encryption, character-encoding, cryptography, octave

I have this octave code

```
PLAINTXT = "ABC";
UNICODED = [];
BINARY_VALUE = [];

for i = PLAINTXT

  UNICODED = [UNICODED, unicode2native(i, "ISO-8859-1")];
  BINARY_VALUE = [BINARY_VALUE, dec2bin(UNICODED)]
%% stop
endfor
```

it takes the plain text "ABC" and convert it using ascii encoding system then converting it to binary
but I need each to be in a separate set
it worked for me when first time when I convert the plain text but it gives me the error "error: horizontal dimensions mismatch (1x7 vs 2x7)" and I don't know what's the problem.

I tried to do as in the code above and I also tried to create another for loop inside the existing on and run the line "BINARY_VALUE = [BINARY_VALUE, dec2bin(UNICODED)]" inside it but it still give me the same result

Answer (score 1):

`dec2bin(a)` for a scalar `a` returns a string, and in Octave a string is a 1xN character array.

`dec2bin(a)` for an array `a` returns a nxN character array (n being the number of elements in `a`).

Hence, in the second iteration when you arrived at `BINARY_VALUE = [BINARY_VALUE, dec2bin(UNICODED)]`:

- `BINARYVALUE` was a 1x7 character array after the 1st iteration
- `UNICODED` is a 1x2 `uint8` array
- `dec2bin(UNICODED)` is hence a 2x7 character array
  So you are indeed trying to append a 2x7 character array to a 1x7 character array, which is not possible.

I'm not sure what you want at the end, but you could do:

```
PLAINTXT = "ABC";
UNICODED = [];

for i = PLAINTXT
  UNICODED = [UNICODED, unicode2native(i, "ISO-8859-1")];
endfor
BINARY_VALUE = dec2bin(UNICODED);
```

Result:

```
>> UNICODED
UNICODED =

  65  66  67

>> BINARY_VALUE
BINARY_VALUE =

1000001
1000010
1000011
```

Comment: Can also do `UNICODED = unicode2native(PLAINTXT, "ISO-8859-1")` and get rid of that loop altogether.